# Rotate around its own axis in OoP with Processing

Tags: arrays, loops, oop, rotation, processing

i am currently a bit stuck in programming a PROCESSING Sketch. Lets say I have a bunch of rectangles that move up the sketch window like bubbles… They have different sizing and color… And I want to let them rotate around its own axis while they move up. I tried using pushMatrix(); and popMatrix(); – and even translate(); but I guess its a bit more complicated because i use OoP and variables in the constructor for X and Y Position of each rectangle…

This is the code to my sketch:

```
Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[10];

void setup() {
  size(360, 640);
  for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
    rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(random(0, width), random(20, 200), random(0, 250));
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
    rectangles[i].display();
    rectangles[i].ascend();
    rectangles[i].top();
  }
}
```

And for the Class Rectangle it is:

```
class Rectangle {
  float x;
  float y;
  float speed;
  float d;
  float c;

  Rectangle(float tempX, float tempD, float tempC) {
    rectMode(CENTER); 
    x = tempX;
    y = height + d/2;
    d  = tempD;
    speed = random(0.5, 2.5);
    c = tempC;
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(c);
    rect(x, y, d, d);
  }
  void ascend() {
    y = y - speed;
  }
  void top() {
    if (y < -d/2) {
      y = height + d/2;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I tried, usually it works:

```
void display() {
  noStroke();
  fill(c);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(radians(frameCount));
  rect(x, y, d, d);
  popMatrix();
}
```

If someone would have an idea or a hint what I am missing I'd be super greatful!
Thank you for any kind of help in advance!

All the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rotating something in place, what usually works best is using `translate` in such a way that you're drawing it "at the origin". In your case, that means that you want to translate such that the first two parameters of `rect()` are both zero. So you translate, then rotate, then draw the rectangle "at the origin".

Solution:

```java
pushMatrix();
translate(x, y);
rotate(radians(frameCount));
rect(0, 0, d, d);
popMatrix();
```

Comment: Hey JSTL,Thank you soooo much! You're the best… Yes drawing "at the origin" is the key! Learned again! Thank you so much for that!